# SQL Server trigger for changing value of column of inserted row according to delta from other table after insert?

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I have 2 tables in my SQL Server database, for example `[Camera]` and `[CameraData]`. How to write a trigger which will change value in `[CameraData]` after row is inserted into `[CameraData]` due to delta in `[Camera]`.

For example we have 2 cameras in `[Camera]`:

- Camera 1 with {id} = 1 and {delta} = null
- Camera 2 with {id} = 2 and {delta} = 3

So when we have automated insert into table `[CameraData]`, f.e. :

```
Id_camera = 2, angle = 30, Changed = null
```

In that case we need to check either we have delta in [Camera] on camera 2 and if that's true we need to modify insert to:

```
Id_camera = 2, angle = 33 (angle + Camera.Delta), Changed = True
```

**Update 1**

According to comment [3] is the column in table `[CameraData]` where angle is placed

```
CREATE TRIGGER Delta_Angle
ON CameraData
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE CameraData
    SET DeltaFlag = 1, [3] = inserted.[3] + i.DeltaAngle
    FROM CameraData h
    INNER JOIN Camera i ON h.ID_Camera = i.ID_Camera
    WHERE i.DeltaAngle != ''
END
```

Comment: So you want to change the value of `angle` in `CameraData` to `angle + inserted.delta`? Is that for all rows for that camera in the table `CameraData`? What attempts have you made so far to achieve this?

Comment: @Larnu, no i want to change the 'angle'  in 'CameraData' to angle + 'Camera.delta' if we have same pk on camera from which was insert and camera in 'Camera' if the last one have delta != 0

Comment: Yes you could use a trigger for this. If you need coding help you need to provide some details. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Isn't that what I said..? Please do share your attempts though, along with making the updates that Sean has advised.

Comment: @Larnu updated question with my code, but i dont know is that right

Comment: If `delta` in `camera` were to be updated, what would that mean for existing rows in `CameraData`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The [delta] in [camera] is a static value - its manually changed to overcome the problem of iprecision of camera module. So every time when camera makes a shot - and data is written in [CameraData] trigger checks either Camera is "broken" and in that case it corrects the angle in each insert. Overall its the system, where cameras send data every hour with their position and some of them send wrong angle, because they're broken.

Comment: Then I'd seriously recommend you reconsider your model. Store the raw (unaltered) data in `CameraData` and compute the corrected values during *retrieval*. It would more accurately reflect reality and *if* you discover that a delta value is wrong later and need to correct it, you can do so without having to correct lots of altered samples. Store *data*, not *computed values*.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much a stab in the dark, as your sample SQL isn't at all representative of the data your describe in your question, however, *maybe* something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Delta_Angle ON CameraData
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE C
    SET Angle = C.Angle + i.delta
    FROM Camera
         JOIN inserted i ON C.CameraID = i.CameraID;
END
```

Notice that I refer to `inserted`; your trigger wasn't. Also, I'm not sure about your clause `i.DeltaAngle != ''`. Considering that `DeltaAngle` appears to be an `int`, it can never have a value of `''` (however, `''` would be implicitly converted to the value `0`).

If this doesn't help, I (again) suggest you read Sean's link and update your post accordingly.